# hook_form_user_register_form_alter (Altering added fields)

Tags: drupal-8

The following does not work: (#description and #attributes does work. #required does not)

```
function bncreports_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
  $form['account']['mail']['#attributes'] = ['onblur' => "getElementById('edit-name').value=this.value.toLowerCase();"];
  $form['account']['name']['#description'] = 'Use Email address as your username';
  $form['account']['name']['#attributes'] = ['onblur' => 'this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();'];
  $form['field_district']['widget']['#required'] = true;
}
```

Why not?

Comment: It seems you have answers [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2021-11-09/hook_form_user_register_form_alter). Without seeing the structure of your form array, we can only guess. Voting to close.

Comment: I figured it out with some help from Drupal.org forums. Got to use $form['field_district']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = true;